# Swift, Tableview should start below

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Start tableview when starting the view from below.

I have a one-dimensional array for the header and a two-dimensional array for the cellen.

Is it possible to start the tableview when calling viewDidLoad () from below? So you have to scroll up.

many thanks

Code for my Header:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell1
    headerView.date.text = aHeaderDate[section]
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return headerView
}
```

Code for my Cell:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell2 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell2", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! TableViewCell2

    let sectionTime = dimArrayTime[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell2.time.text = sectionTime
    return cell2

}
```

Example, so it is now:
[image]

That's how it should be:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to do? Show what kind of array you have and share screenshot what you want to draw with your current available array.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to achieve that is to transform table view and its cells:

Mirror the table view:

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

In `viewForHeaderInSection` and `cellForRowAt` mirror those views as well:

```
headerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)

cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

Comment: that is a very good idea. But then my cell always appears over the header.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I solved the problem by simply flipping my arrays with the array.reversed () function before displaying them in my tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following code

```
[tableView reloadData];
int lastRowNumber = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following source code

```
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: model.dataArray.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
})
```